# self signed certificate in certificate chain on github copilot

Tags: github, github-copilot

I installed the GitHub copilot but the extension do not work, always show the following error **:**

[image]

> GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "self signed certificate in certificate chain"
>
> Source: GitHub Copilot (Extension) <kbd>Show Output log</kbd>

What could I do to solve this ?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-network-errors-for-github-copilot#troubleshooting-certificate-related-errors

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Copilot error: “***GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain***” is generally caused using CoPilot behind a Corporate network.

- Most corporate networks have a ‘Man-in-the-middle’ appliance that dynamically breaks open all secure SSL traffic leaving home to enter the internet. This ensures they can inspected any traffic leaving, including your online banking. Usually automation scrubs the traffic looking for theft of company secrets or IP and raises alerts. It all gets logged and reviewed further if need be.
- This action leaves behind a fake cert chain as a fingerprint. The cert for the called site is replaced with a fake, and one signed by the company’s own private CA authority. Hence the self-signed cert in the cert chain error.
- From any company device (Phones\Laptop) the company CA is already installed as a trusted CA. So the local browsers and other desktop apps trust this faked cert chain - and so do not raise any concerns someone is snooping your secure network traffic (the company does own the network and the device).
- By default VSCode is not trusting the installed desktop certs, and so it noticed that the GitHub cert is no longer signed by a trusted public CA authority.
- As **Rypox** states above, the VSCode extension ‘Win-CA’ (**must be set to ‘append’ mode**) solves this issue. It tells VSCode to also trust the CA’s installed on the employees desktop. This makes VSCode happy again trusting the fake cert chain. No '*whitelisting*' needed and not '*VPN*' related. But certinly not that obvious either. An interesting CA trust issue.
- Confirming this does exist is easy from your browser. Go to any outside site (like Amazon) and review the sites “Cert” to see who the CA’s are (Certification Path). It should ‘not’ contain any reference to your company. Look at that same cert from outside the company network on your own personal laptop.

… “bit of a glitch in the Matrix”, installing Win-CA helps hides it again and all looks back to normal.

Comment: Do you happen to know a fix for PyCharm too? Thank you very much!

Comment: it can happen under VPN connection

Comment: Do you know how to do it with VS2022? I can't turn off my corporate VPN and I cannot know what certificates my VPN uses to work around the problem, any ideas?

Comment: Any solution for Webstorm?

Comment: The `win-ca` extension got me fixed up using `append`!  I'm running: Win10 VM, Copilot, VSCode, WSL1, Ubuntu 20. Copilot had been working on Ubuntu (WSL1, guest). The cert error was only happening on the Windows side. Don't forget to restart VSCode.

Comment: Any solution for visual studio 2022? This workaround works perfectly for vscode

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75239728/1244910) happens to also work for VS 2022.

Comment: corporate firewalls and their on-path attack modes - the gift the just keeps giving! Thanks for this solution - win-ca seems to be working out just fine once i set it to append as you point out :D

Answer (score 59):

I had the same issue with a corporate proxy. The [win-ca](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ukoloff.win-ca&ssr=false#overview) extension resolved it.

Steps to fix the issue:

1. Install [win-ca](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ukoloff.win-ca&ssr=false#overview)
2. In the `win-ca` settings, switch `Inject` to `append` mode (it's not the default).
3. Restart VsCode

PS: This is a Windows only solution. For Macs, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367058/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-github-copilot).

Comment: I used this on my mac Mac CA VSCode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=linhmtran168.mac-ca-vscode

Comment: this was easy.. and it worked.. better than writing script.

Comment: Can confirm this also worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: You need to follow the path to set the `append` mode selection File / Preferences / Settings / Extensions / win-ca

Answer (score 30):

For any MacOS users, I have found that the VSCode extension linhmtran168.mac-ca-vscode can help as well with this. It is similar to the previously mentioned win-ca.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=linhmtran168.mac-ca-vscode

Comment: this worked for me as well. just had to install it and restart vscode

Comment: How secure is this?

Comment: Can confirm that this extension does the trick on a Mac!

Comment: Yes, it work perfect @tklives

Comment: Works great. Extension is also called "Mac CA VSCode". Don't let the extension name above scare you. Grabs certs from Keychain Access and loads them to the TLS context in VSCode. Infinitely more secure than somehow disabling TLS.

Answer (score 21):

On macOS and linux, you can use this script to monkey patch the Copilot extension to make this work:

**Update:**
Also fixes copilot chat error:

> Error on conversation request. Check the log for more details.

```bash
_VSCODEDIR="$HOME/.vscode/extensions"
_COPILOTDIR=$(ls "${_VSCODEDIR}" | grep -E "github.copilot-[1-9].*" | sort -V | tail -n1) # For copilot
_COPILOTDEVDIR=$(ls "${_VSCODEDIR}" | grep "github.copilot-nightly-" | sort -V | tail -n1) # For copilot-nightly
_COPILOTCHATDIR=$(ls "${_VSCODEDIR}" | grep -E "github.copilot-chat-*" | sort -V | tail -n1) # For copilot-chat
_EXTENSIONFILEPATH="${_VSCODEDIR}/${_COPILOTDIR}/dist/extension.js"
_DEVEXTENSIONFILEPATH="${_VSCODEDIR}/${_COPILOTDEVDIR}/dist/extension.js"
_CHATEXTENSIONFILEPATH="${_VSCODEDIR}/${_COPILOTCHATDIR}/dist/extension.js"

if [[ -f "$_EXTENSIONFILEPATH" ]]; then
    echo "Found Copilot Extension, applying 'rejectUnauthorized' patches to '$_EXTENSIONFILEPATH'..."
    perl -pi -e 's/,rejectUnauthorized:[a-z]}(?!})/,rejectUnauthorized:false}/g' ${_EXTENSIONFILEPATH}
    sed -i.bak 's/d={...l,/d={...l,rejectUnauthorized:false,/g' ${_EXTENSIONFILEPATH}
else
    echo "Couldn't find the extension.js file for Copilot, please verify paths and try again or ignore if you don't have Copilot..."
fi
if [[ -f "$_DEVEXTENSIONFILEPATH" ]]; then
    echo "Found Copilot-Nightly Extension, applying 'rejectUnauthorized' patches to '$_DEVEXTENSIONFILEPATH'..."
    perl -pi -e 's/,rejectUnauthorized:[a-z]}(?!})/,rejectUnauthorized:false}/g' ${_DEVEXTENSIONFILEPATH}
    sed -i.bak 's/d={...l,/d={...l,rejectUnauthorized:false,/g' ${_DEVEXTENSIONFILEPATH}
else
    echo "Couldn't find the extension.js file for Copilot-Nightly, please verify paths and try again or ignore if you don't have Copilot-Nightly..."
fi
if [[ -f "$_CHATEXTENSIONFILEPATH" ]]; then
    echo "Found Copilot-Chat Extension, applying 'rejectUnauthorized' patches to '$_CHATEXTENSIONFILEPATH'..."
    perl -pi -e 's/,rejectUnauthorized:[a-z]}(?!})/,rejectUnauthorized:false}/g' ${_CHATEXTENSIONFILEPATH}
    sed -i.bak 's/d={...l,/d={...l,rejectUnauthorized:false,/g' ${_CHATEXTENSIONFILEPATH}
else
    echo "Couldn't find the extension.js file for Copilot-Chat, please verify paths and try again or ignore if you don't have Copilot-Chat..."
fi
```

Save as something like `monkey-patch-copilot.sh`, then `chmod +x monkey-patch-copilot.sh`. You should then be able to run: `./monkey-patch-copilot.sh` to apply the patch.

> **Note:** I am not the original author. This was found on the Copilot feedback forum.

Comment: I'd been looking for a fix for so long. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your script for the PyCharm / IntelliJ plugin. There's no `extension.js` in the dist folder, but `agent.js` and `service.js` exists, and contain `rejectUnauthorized:` a bunch of places. `d={...l` isn't anywhere to find, but I've got `d={...c` and `d={...n`. How do I determine which should be replaced? If I uploaded the files somewhere, would you be willing to help me with this?

Comment: Do you happen to know a fix for PyCharm too?

Comment: If you are using the SSH plugin for vscode, make sure to change the first line to `_VSCODEDIR="$HOME/.vscode-server/extensions"`

Comment: Works on linux as well!

Comment: this made progress here on my Ubuntu machine, since I'm on a corporate machine, and now I got a new error on the Output window:

`[ERROR] [default] [2024-01-08T13:55:41.684Z] Extension activation failed: "Cancelled"`

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution for this which works for me in case of Intellij. I have blogged about it at https://sidd.io/2023/01/github-copilot-self-signed-cert-issue/

At a high level I think the architecture of the plugin might be same :

`IDE Native CoPilot Plugin` ---making RPC call---> `NodeJS based CoPilot Agent`

And this `NodeJS based CoPilot Agent` agent has issues with the Self Signed Certs (at least in my case).

Fix is as follows :

1. Export the self-signed certificate in discussion
2. Convert it into `.pem` format if not already
3. Export the path of this `.pem` cert to `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` variable
4. Restart your IDE and it should work

Comment: This answer will help solve the issue for Visual Studio. It feels more correct then installing an extension.

Comment: How do you know which certificate is used for a given VPN provider???

Comment: @NicolasBelley in my understanding if you have installed an VPN provider on your machine then a Root CA would also have been installed in your machine. Ex: if you are using a Mac then you should check this under "Keychain Access" in "Certificates" and you should find it.

Comment: This works also under Windows for JetBrains IDEs: set `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` variable in the "Edit environment variables for your account" control panel (no admin needed), to an absolute path like "C:\path\to\ca-bundle.crt"

Comment: what certificate "is in discussion"?

Comment: Is there any complete step-by-step solution for Visual Studio 2022, yet? How do I "Export the self-signed certificate"?, etc...

Comment: For emacs users, add this to your init.el file

```
(setenv "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS" "/path/to/cer/file")
```

Answer (score 3):

Corporate VPN was the problem (same as @mark-derry's).

Jetbrain's PyCharm / DataSpell allows to accept self signed certificates.

VSCode doesn't seem to have this option yet.

Comment: I tried adding the self signed certificates according to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-server-certificates.html), but it does not work. I also tried **Accept non-trusted certificates automatically**. not working either. Did you manage to make JetBrains/PyCharm copilot plugin work with corporate vpn that has a self signed certificates?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [win-ca][1]
   [1]: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ukoloff.win-ca
2. Press CTRL + SHIFT + P Search for @ext:ukoloff.win-ca
3. Put Win-Ca: Inject to **append**
4. Restart the IDE
5. Start Coding

Comment: This is already covered in the second most voted answer on this very question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71826748/2442804

Comment: @luk2302 There is no reference to how to apply the append. That's the reason why I posted here

Comment: The answer referenced does have this information now

Comment: @ZachSaucier There is no reference to how to apply the append. That's the reason why I posted here

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a similar error to what I am getting. I believe that the source of this in our corporate network is a ssl inspection process such that when the https traffic is opened and inspected that it breaks the certificate chain and this error shows up. A fix would be to add the GitHub Copilot servers to the ssl inspection whitelist so that that traffic is not inspected.

Comment: have the same problem; unfortunately getting things whitelisted could be quite challenging at the corps

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was ***ZScaler***, the corporate annoyance. Fortunately we are allowed to exit the app. After exiting Zscaler and reloading the CoPilot extention in VSCode CoPilot worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem in my company and we have solved it following these steps:

1. Enter IntelliJ
2. Ctrl + Alt + S (Settings)
3. Search by "cert"
4. Mark option "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically"
5. Restart IntelliJ

[image: 3., 4.]

Saludos a todos desde España.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using VS 2022 - check your options and update as below:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Easy!
Method 1 : just excute this code.

> git config --global http.sslVerify false

Method 2:
FOllow this guide! and Thank me later because I have saved you a time of husel ? :) . you're welcome!

https://mattferderer.com/fix-git-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-windows

Comment: The problem with an GitHub Copilot extension, not with the git connections