# Unable to use GitHub Copilot on WebStorm (JetBrains) when behind corporate proxy

Tags: github, webstorm, intellij-plugin, github-copilot

I'm behind a corporate proxy and unable to use GitHub Copilot on WebStorm.
This is the error that I'm getting:

[image]

GitHub Copilot is working on VsCode after using the monkey patch solution given in [self signed certificate in certificate chain on github copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367058/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-github-copilot)

Is there any similar way to use it for WebStorm?
I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

When using VDI, I encountered a self-signed certificate issue (I find VDI environments similar to internal corporate VPNs). My development environment is Windows 11 (VDI) with IntelliJ IDEA 2024. I resolved it by following these steps:

1. Open github.com.
2. Click on the lock icon to the left of the browser address bar on github.com.
3. Verify that the connection is secure.
4. To the left of the "Close" button, click on "Show Certificate."
5. Go to the "Details" tab.
6. Click the "Export" button.
7. Open IntelliJ IDEA.
8. Navigate to "Settings."
9. Under "Tools," select "Server Certificate."
10. Click "Add."
11. Choose the certificate you exported earlier.
12. Click "OK."

Now your GitHub Copilot should work.