# How do i fix Something went wrong checking access: self signed certificate in certificate chain when using Copilot labs

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, certificate, self-signed-certificate, github-copilot

Im behind a corporate proxy but the strange thing is that i can use Copilot extension without any problem but not the Copilot labs.

I've tried following:

- installed win-ca extension and set inject to append
- tried disabling: "Http: System Certificates"
- tried disabling: "Http: Proxy Strict SSL"

Nothing works and now im stuck. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [self signed certificate in certificate chain on github copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367058/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-github-copilot)

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered on [self signed certificate in certificate chain on github copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367058/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-github-copilot?rq=2).

The accepted answer seems to work for Windows users, although there's another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889953/1106735) suitable to Mac OS users.

Comment: please flag duplicate questions to be closed instead of answering them. click the "flag" button under the question post. please also see [answer], and [/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

Only installing win-ca extension and restarting vscode worked for me , didnt had to do any other setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue as OP. win-ca extension is set to append, but still getting self-signed cert error on my corporate laptop.

installed win-ca extension and set inject to append
tried disabling: "Http: System Certificates"
tried disabling: "Http: Proxy Strict SSL"**strong text**

I had Zscaler installed. I had to disable "Internet Security" on it, followed by ctrl+sh+p Developer:reload window, which restarted the win-ca extension. Then I was able to use copilot.  Hope that helps