# Visual Studio 2022: Github Copilot : Request Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

Im trying to use the GitlabCopilot extension for visual studio professional 2022.
I have a work-VPN that i cant turn off.
This is the error
[image: error]

I think this is related to my question, but solutions dont work:
[self signed certificate in certificate chain on github copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367058/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-github-copilot)

Comment: Update, tried to install the github certificate on credentials storage, but it didnt work neither