# Copilot error "Error on conversation request. Check the log for more details"

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I installed copilot extension in VS code and activated my membership online. I see the chat area in VS code but whenever I type a question I get the response "Error on conversation request. Check the log for more details." When I check the logs I see only the following:

```
2023-09-22 14:58:18.699 [info] update#setState idle
2023-09-22 14:58:19.398 [info] WSL is not installed, so could not detect WSL profiles
2023-09-22 14:58:48.711 [info] update#setState checking for updates
2023-09-22 14:58:48.929 [info] update#setState idle
```

I installed WSL just to try if it solves the problem, but it did not work. Does anyone know how I can get copilot to work?

Comment: which output channel is that from? which output channels did you check?

Comment: These are the contents of the log file

Comment: maybe see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues/366

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A follow up on this issue. Copilot worked for some time on VS code insiders and then stopped working. Whenever I would use it I would get the error message 'Error on conversation request. Check the log for more details.'. So the solution was short lived. I tried uninstalling and re-installing VS code but that did not work. Finally I got it to work by following the solution in this post:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues/439

Basically, you need to install the win-ca extension, then go to the settings of the extension and select 'append' from the drop-down list. Once I did that, Copilot was running properly in both the insiders version and the regular version of VS code.

Comment: see also [self signed certificate in certificate chain on github copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71367058/11107541)

Comment: What if you're on Linux?

Comment: In my case this comment from the same mentioned issue helped: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues/439#issuecomment-1771637264

Comment: Same issue & this solution actually works for me too. But do we know why does this error occur & where do we find logs for this.

Comment: i have this error on linux ubuntu, is there a solution?!

Comment: I am using a windows machine. I am not sure about Linux.

Comment: It worked. Resolved my issue. I share my GitHub Copilot log running in windows11 with WSL. My Ubuntu 22 laptop presents no issues
```bash
2023-10-31T21:39:57.689Z [INFO] [chat fetch] chat model copilot-chat
2023-10-31T21:40:02.271Z [INFO] [chat fetch] request.response: [https://api.githubcopilot.com/chat/completions], took 4581 ms
2023-10-31T21:40:02.274Z [INFO] [streamMessages] message 0 returned. finish reason: [stop]
2023-10-31T21:40:02.276Z [INFO] [streamChoices] request done: headerRequestId: [54eca7ff-ec36-44d7-bfdc-dcdffae51bb9] model deployment ID: [x31dbc412c159]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get copilot to work by installing Visual Studio Code - Insiders 1.83.0. For some reason it did not work on Visual Studio Code 1.82.2, but it works on the Insiders version 1.83.0.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the feature VSCode Workspace Trust

it gives permissions to decide whether code in the project folder can be executed by VSCode and extensions without your explicit approval. I have multiple folders and many projects in my workspace.

Leave a folder in Restricted Mode to increase security. You can always enable trust later.
Workspace Trust provides an extra layer of security when working with unfamiliar code, by preventing automatic code execution of any code in your workspace if the workspace is open in "Restricted Mode".

trial and error and removing the restrictions and addind the GitHub copilot domain as a trusted domain can help resolve the issue without installing extensions.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this actually relates to the problem in the question post. workspace trust isn't really about what domains VS Code will trust. It's about what _workspaces_ it will trust (which is a local thing)

Comment: @starball thanks for your inputs. That resolved the issues for my case. I am using a work provided laptop with win11. In my Linux personal machine I face no issues. After adding domains and trusting my workspaces it worked

Comment: what domain patterns exactly did you need to add trust for?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a firewall set up, check that you've enabled all the domains that GitHub Copilot needs. The most up to date list can be found in https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-firewall-settings-for-github-copilot#urls-to-add-to-an-allowlist. Quoting from what I see there at the time of this writing:

> Due to GitHub Copilot's interaction with a remote machine learning model and its update checking functionality, it is recommended to include the following domain URLs in the allowlist, marking them as trusted either in the user interface or within your deployment scripts.
>
> | Domain and/or URL | Purpose |
> | --- | --- |
> | `https://github.com/login/*` | Authentication |
> | `https://api.github.com/user` | User Management |
> | `https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/*` | User Management |
> | `https://copilot-telemetry.githubusercontent.com/telemetry` | Telemetry |
> | `https://default.exp-tas.com/` | Telemetry |
> | `https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/` | API service for {% data variables.product.prodname_copilot_short %} suggestions |
> | `https://origin-tracker.githubusercontent.com` | API service for {% data variables.product.prodname_copilot_short %} suggestions |
> | `https://*.githubcopilot.com` | API service for {% data variables.product.prodname_copilot_short %} suggestions |
>
> Additional domains and URLs may require allowlisting, depending on your organization's security policies and the editors in use. For more information about specific editors, see "[Further reading](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-firewall-settings-for-github-copilot#further-reading)."

Note: Might also want to check that the [general VS Code domains](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_common-hostnames) are allowed through as well.

The rest of the GH Copilot troubleshooting docs might be helpful to you as well:

- [Common Issues with GitHub Copilot](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-common-issues-with-github-copilot)
- [Viewing Logs](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/viewing-logs-for-github-copilot-in-your-environment)
- [Network Errors](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-network-errors-for-github-copilot)
- [Copilot Chat](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-issues-with-github-copilot-chat)