# "Error on conversation request" VSCode - Github CoPilot error message

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I just installed CoPilot for VSCode and am getting the error message "Error on conversation request" This is the output that the chat gives me:
`2023-09-26T14:53:49.251Z [INFO] [auth] Logged in as eeberman 2023-09-26T14:53:52.034Z [INFO] [chat] copilot token chat_enabled: true 2023-09-26T14:53:52.041Z [INFO] [auth] Got Copilot token for eeberman 2023-09-26T14:53:58.205Z [INFO] [chat fetch] engine https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/chat 2023-09-26T14:53:58.205Z [INFO] [chat fetch] modelMaxTokenWindow 4096 2023-09-26T14:53:58.205Z [INFO] [chat fetch] chat model copilot-chat`

I assume this is me being a beginner and am missing something relatively simple. Please let me know what I can do to resolve. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling copilot. Still got the same error.

Comment: this question is possible a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77160160/11107541

Comment: see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues/366

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copilot error "Error on conversation request. Check the log for more details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160160/copilot-error-error-on-conversation-request-check-the-log-for-more-details)