# Signing into Gitub Copilot via IntelliJ gives self signed certificate in certificate

Tags: github, intellij-idea, github-copilot

I am trying to sign into my Github account through IntelliJ so I can use Github Copilot. When I enter the confirmation code, I am welcomed with a success screen:

[success screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5YF9.png)

However, back in IntelliJ, I never move beyond this screen, even after waiting for hours:

[stalling screen in Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWhb1.png)

Upon looking at IntelliJ logs, I see this error:

```
#copilot - [default] unhandledRejection: FetchError: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at fetch (C:\snapshot\copilot-client\node_modules\@adobe\helix-fetch\src\fetch\index.js:99:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at cachingFetch (C:\snapshot\copilot-client\node_modules\@adobe\helix-fetch\src\fetch\index.js:288:16)
    at HG.fetch (C:\snapshot\copilot-client\lib\src\network\helix.ts:78:22)
    at C:\snapshot\copilot-client\lib\src\auth\deviceFlow.ts:117:32 {
  type: 'system',
  _name: 'FetchError',
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
  errno: undefined,
  erroredSysCall: undefined
}
```

I understand this issue could be because I am behind a corporate VPN, but I have not found a workaround.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367058/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-github-copilot), but it is a VSCode-centric question, and the solution refers to a plugin that has no equivalent in the IntelliJ ecosystem, as far as I can tell. The IntelliJ-specific suggestions in that post did not work for me. I am able to use Copilot in VSCode.

I have tried modifying proxy settings, signing in without being logged into a VPN, and updated IntelliJ and the Copilot plugin to the newest versions.I have reinstalled the plugin, and researched other workarounds.

I also tried fooling around with SSL settings:
git config --global http.sslVerify false

I am not yet able to embed images, so I have to put links (not enough rep).